# AlarmManager substitute in iOS

Tags: android, ios

I have an Android app that uses AlarmManager to display a window when an alarm is fired.  Think of this like a "time to take your medicine" screen... I need them to log certain things down immediately, regardless if the user is currently using my app or in another app.  I would like to port my app to iOS but I know this type of functionality isn't allowed.

Is there something in iOS that is similar?  I was thinking I could use notifications to accomplish something close to this.  Like a notification would come up saying “log your medicine”.. and clicking the notification would load the medication screen.  However, if the user is currently inside my application will a notification display?  I am assuming no.

Thoughts?

```
    // Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, responseInfo.getResponseGuidID().intValue(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You could always use a notification if they aren't in your app, and if you detect they are in your app then show a system dialog instead

Comment: @Quinn, just to be clear.  The user could disable app notifications or be in DND mode and my notifications would stop working, right?

Comment: yes I think that’s correct, if they don’t give you notification permissions then they would not get the notifications (even silently in the foreground)